# How can I talk to UniProt over HTTP in Python?

Tags: python, http, user-agent, bioinformatics

I'm trying to get some results from UniProt, which is a protein database (details are not important). I'm trying to use some script that translates from one kind of ID to another. I was able to do this manually on the browser, but could not do it in Python.

In http://www.uniprot.org/faq/28 there are some sample scripts. I tried the Perl one and it seems to work, so the problem is my Python attempts. The (working) script is:

```
## tool_example.pl ##
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $base = 'http://www.uniprot.org';
my $tool = 'mapping';
my $params = {
  from => 'ACC', to => 'P_REFSEQ_AC', format => 'tab',
  query => 'P13368 P20806 Q9UM73 P97793 Q17192'
};

my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;
push @{$agent->requests_redirectable}, 'POST';
print STDERR "Submitting...\n";
my $response = $agent->post("$base/$tool/", $params);

while (my $wait = $response->header('Retry-After')) {
  print STDERR "Waiting ($wait)...\n";
  sleep $wait;
  print STDERR "Checking...\n";
  $response = $agent->get($response->base);
}

$response->is_success ?
  print $response->content :
  die 'Failed, got ' . $response->status_line . 
    ' for ' . $response->request->uri . "\n";
```

My questions are:

1) How would you do that in Python?

2) Will I be able to massively "scale" that (i.e., use a lot of entries in the query field)?

Comment: It was pretty much opening the same address as I would in the browser, with urllib2.urlopen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**question #1:**

This can be done using python's urllibs:

```
import urllib, urllib2
import time
import sys

query = ' '.join(sys.argv)   

# encode params as a list of 2-tuples
params = ( ('from','ACC'), ('to', 'P_REFSEQ_AC'), ('format','tab'), ('query', query))
# url encode them
data = urllib.urlencode(params)    
url = 'http://www.uniprot.org/mapping/'

# fetch the data
try:
    foo = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
except urllib2.HttpError, e:
    if e.code == 503:
        # blah blah get the value of the header...
        wait_time = int(e.hdrs.get('Retry-after', 0))
        print 'Sleeping %i seconds...' % (wait_time,)
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        foo = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)


# foo is a file-like object, do with it what you will.
foo.read()
```

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work (even after replacing that '=' with '==')... Thanks.:)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you are using Python 2.5.
We can use [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html?highlight=httplib#module-httplib) to directly call the web site:

```
import httplib, urllib
querystring = {}
#Build the query string here from the following keys (query, format, columns, compress, limit, offset)
querystring["query"] = "" 
querystring["format"] = "" # one of html | tab | fasta | gff | txt | xml | rdf | rss | list
querystring["columns"] = "" # the columns you want comma seperated
querystring["compress"] = "" # yes or no
## These may be optional
querystring["limit"] = "" # I guess if you only want a few rows
querystring["offset"] = "" # bring on paging 

##From the examples - query=organism:9606+AND+antigen&format=xml&compress=no
##Delete the following and replace with your query
querystring = {}
querystring["query"] =  "organism:9606 AND antigen" 
querystring["format"] = "xml" #make it human readable
querystring["compress"] = "no" #I don't want to have to unzip

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.uniprot.org")
conn.request("GET", "/uniprot/?"+ urllib.urlencode(querystring))
r1 = conn.getresponse()
if r1.status == 200:
   data1 = r1.read()
   print data1  #or do something with it
```

You could then make a function around creating the query string and you should be away.

Comment: This unfortunately has the same effect as my other attempts - hanging on for minutes. Also, it's "GET", which to my understanding limits it to url size only..

Comment: I think this is the point of the limit and columns query values, not knowing what i am returning I can't give good values for these.  The GET limits what you send not what you receive.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off using the Protein Identifier Cross Reference service from the EBI to convert one set of IDs to another. It has a very good REST interface.

http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/picr/

I should also mention that UniProt has very good webservices available. Though if you are tied to using simple http requests for some reason then its probably not useful.

Answer (score 1):

check this out `bioservices`.  they interface a lot of databases through Python. 
https://pythonhosted.org/bioservices/_modules/bioservices/uniprot.html

```
conda install bioservices --yes
```

Answer (score 1):

in complement to O.rka answer:

**Question 1:**

```
from bioservices import UniProt
u = UniProt()
res = u.get_df("P13368 P20806 Q9UM73 P97793 Q17192".split())
```

This returns a dataframe with all information about each entry.

**Question 2:** same answer. This should scale up.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of bioservices

Comment: Related to this: Does something comparable exist for `KEGG()`, that one e.g. passes a list of reactions, metabolites or KOs?

Answer (score 0):

There is a python package in pip which does exactly what you want

```
pip install uniprot-mapper
```